# Can mutual inductance be used to measure weight?

Tags: electromagnetic-induction, weight

It's been a long time since I completed my engineering degree and haven't worked in the industry since graduation so please allow for some supidiy on my part. I am trying to determine whether it would be possible to build a rudimentary sensor to measure weight by harnessing mutual inductance.

[image]

I'm working on the principle/assumption that when a ferromagnetic rod in placed within the two coils, the induced current and/or voltage in the secondary coil will change based on the depth of insertion of the rod. If there is a known force exerted in the opposite direction (compression spring) one would be able to determine the rough weight exerted on rod by the fluctuation in current/voltage in the secondary coil.

I was hoping that some very basic linear weight sensors could be created which do not utilise strain gauges. Am I barking up the wrong tree ?

Any advise very much appreciated.

Comment: Can be used oscillations of the system with a frequency of $\omega =\sqrt {k/m}$. Then the frequency of the current in the winding will show the mass. You can use one winding.

Comment: Sounds like you are on your way to re-inventing the _[linear variable differential transformer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_variable_differential_transformer)_

Comment: Also note: What you are describing is a _position_ sensor, which you are proposing to use to measure the displacement of a spring scale. But spring scales are not the most precise, no matter what sensor you use. High-precision weighing machines generally balance the unknown weight against a known weight or other known force in such a way that the position of the machine's moving parts is always the same at the moment when the reading is obtained.

Answer (score 0):

In your diagram, picture coil 1 with a fixed current and a hook on the bottom, free to slide up and down on a fixed non-magnetic core inserted from the top.  Coil 2 would need to extend well above the top of coil 1.  The force required to support coil 1 and a hanging weight in a given position should be a linear function of the current in coil 2.  You don't want a magnetic core because it's magnetization could change in a non-linear fashion.